# Sharing a variables file between less and scss

Tags: css, sass, less

I have two large projects, each project has a relatively simple web front-end with multiple themes: different colors and fonts. These themes are the same across projects

One of these projects uses scss and the other uses less. Neither are my strong suit and i am not allowed to make them use one or the other in both places. What i would like to do however is have a shared folder with a file for each theme which could hold all the variables for that theme.

This would allow me to avoid duplication and make maintenance slightly easier, while promoting consistency between the two projects which *must* have the same colors and fonts between them. Is there a relatively simple way of doing this?

Comment: You can use bundling tool such as webpack to load both sass and less in both the application.

Comment: It's also possible to load JSON files with some additional work. But you'd better stick with your current solution.

Comment: @scheme You can use both less and sass simultaneously as in the end everything is compiled to css only.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Yes i understand, however i'd like to have some global variables which are used in the scss and the less files defined only once rather than duplicated.

Comment: @Scheme probably this can help you out https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-scss-convertor

Comment: You can import `scss` files within Less using [`less-plugin-sass2less`](https://github.com/mediafreakch/less-plugin-sass2less).

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature) documentation. You'll see that SASS and LESS although similar both have different ways of declaring variables. So Importing a LESS file to a SASS file, and vice-versa, will not have the result you expect.

I would suggest, since it's an easy change, adapting the LESS file to a SASS file or a SASS file to a LESS file and create the base for what you want from there.

Comment: I'm aware they declare variables with a different syntax, but given the popularity of both of them I imagine there is a relatively simple way to use the same variables in both. I mean a very simple script could generate a less file from the scss file as a part of the build process. I'll probably just go with that if there is not a elegant way of doing it already.

Comment: A simple "find and replace" would do the trick, but since you want a script:
here you go: https://csspre.com/convert/